# Detect denormalized-data inconsistencies in just one SQL query?

Tags: sql, denormalization

I have some denormalized data in two tables. It's denormalized because from the DepositsAndWithdrawals table (second one below) I can get the current customer's balance, but for fast access I keep it in the UserBalance table (first one below) so I don't need to sum all of his operations all the time:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| ID | Username | Balance |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | Alice    | 50      |
+----+----------+---------+
| 2  | Bob      | 20      |
+----+----------+---------+
| 3  | Charles  | 30      |
+----+----------+---------+
```

```
+----+------------+---------+
| ID | CustomerID | Amount  |
+----+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1          | 50      |
+----+------------+---------+
| 2  | 2          | 80      |
+----+------------+---------+
| 3  | 3          | 10      |
+----+------------+---------+
| 4  | 2          | -60     |
+----+------------+---------+
| 5  | 3          | 20      |
+----+------------+---------+
```

This brings up a consistency problem in case there are race conditions in the system. So, in order to detect those, I'd like to have a daily DB query that detects balance inconsistencies (that is, when `SUM(amount)` is different from `balance`). How to do such a JOIN in a single SQL statement?

Comment: Isn't better to prevent the inconsistency, rather than try to detect and fix it?

Comment: yes, but this is to learn SQL better, I guess I need the GROUPBY clause but I'm not sure

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the race conditions could be that brings in data inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.ID As customerId, A.BALANCE, SUM(B.AMOUNT) AS REAL_BALANCE FROM A
 JOIN B on A.ID = B.customerId
GROUP BY A.ID, A.BALANCE
HAVING SUM(B.AMOUNT) <> A.BALANCE
```

Where `B` is your `DepositsAndWithdrawals` table and `A` is `UserBalance` table